# extract content from Object, Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, object, mean

I'm using the MEAN stack and are trying to extract info from an object, but the attributs change depending on lots of factors so can't call them. Is there a way I can get the information in another way? The data will be used to update different things in my monogdb.

Simple info about my database: 3 collections. Users, Years, Courses.

Year: id, userid, courses {courseid, grade, }

Course: id, name, credits etc.

I've managed to send the information to the nodejs file but can't do anything with it. Below is the result of the consolelog I do of the information. How do I get the information out of the object so that I can update my database?

**Result from the log**

```
Object {year: Object, grade: Object}
    grade:Object
          574d8ce6bfb4ea470a2e10c7:"3"
          __proto__:Object
    year:Object
         574e8cf5ae8fc00917ded99b:true
         __proto__:Object

  Grade contains the id of the course for which I want to change the grade and the grade 
  I want to change to. 
  Year contains the Id of the year in which the course is stored.
```

**home/index.html**

Below only contains the form. The variable year.XXX iterates over a year (Retrieved from the database).

year.course = {id: XX, grade:YY}

theCourse iterates over all courses in the database to get course-specific information.

vm.change is the variable sent on to the controller.

```
 <form>
     <div class="panel-heading " ><b>  YEAR {{year.year}}</b>
         <label style="float: right;"> Edit
             <input type="checkbox" id="year._id" value="year.id" ng-model="vm.change.year[year._id]"/>
                </label>
                <div><p>Sum of Credits: {{year.totalCredits}}</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body hideyear" >
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h4>HT</h4>
                    <table class="table " >
                        <tr class="active" >
                            <th><b>Course code</b></th>
                            <th><b>Grade</b></th>
                            <th><b>Update Grade</b></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody ng-repeat= "course in year.courses">
                        <tr ng-repeat="theCourse in vm.courses" ng-if="theCourse._id==course.id && (theCourse.term=='HT1'||theCourse.term=='HT2')">
                            <td >{{theCourse.courseCode}}</td>
                            <td>{{course.grade}}</td>
                            <td ><select ng-disabled="!vm.change.year[year._id]" ng-model="vm.change.grade[course.id]">
                                <option disabled selected value> -- update grade -- </option>
                                <option value="NA">NA</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="G">G</option>
                                <option value="U">U</option>
                            </select></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!vm.change.year[year._id]" ng-click="vm.saveChange(vm.change)">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
```

**index.controller.js**

```
 function saveChange(change){
        console.log(change)
}
```

**EDIT**

In a file called **app.js** vm to Controller as and choose which controller to use:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ui.router'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    /*
    Connects the right subpage with corresponding controller and url.
    */

    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // default route
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home/index.html',
            controller: 'Home.IndexController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            data: { activeTab: 'home' }
        });
    }
```

When the html loads, the controller gathers some information from the database thats used on most parts of the page.

```
function initController() {
        // get current user
        UserService.GetCurrent().then(function (user) {
            vm.user = user;

        });
        //Gets all years in the database
        YearService.GetAll().then(function (years) {
            vm.years = years;
        });
        // Gets all courses in the databased.
        CourseService.GetAll().then(function (courses) {
            vm.courses = courses;
        });
    }
```

All the gets in the initcontroller above does pretty much the same thing, so I'll show the process for one of them, YearSevice.GetAll, calls **app-service/year.service.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('YearService', Service);

    function Service($http, $q){
        var service =  {};
        service.GetAll = GetAll;
        return service;

        function GetAll() {
        return $http.get('/api/year/getAll').then(handleSuccess, handleError);
        }
```

with the $http.get we go via the server to a server-side controller, **year.controller**.

```
var config = require('config.json');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var YearService = require('services/year.service');

// routes

router.get('/getAll', getAll);

function getAll(req,res){
    YearService.getAll()
         .then(function(result){
            if(result){
                res.send(result);
            }else{
                res.sendStatus(404);
            }
        })
         .catch(function(err){
            res.status(400).send(err);
         });
}
```

YearService.getAll calls the server-side services: services/year.services.js

```
var config = require('config.json');
var _ = require('lodash');
var Q = require('q');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');


//Connectionsstring to the mongo database, if the app is runed on openshift the connectionstring value will change.
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mean-stack-registration-login-example";
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL){
    connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + "studycontrol";
}
var db = mongo.db(connectionString, { native_parser: true });


db.bind('years');
db.bind('users');
db.bind('courses');

var service = {};
service.getAll = getAll;
module.exports = service;


function getAll(){
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    //
    db.collection('years').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(err);
        deferred.resolve(result);
        return deferred.promise;
    });
    return deferred.promise;

}
```

And the collection is returned allt the way to the html-code. Sending new information to the database has the same structure but includes an object to be sent with the whole time. In previous cases the object have been easy to construct, but now I need to send course-code, year-id and grade and am trying to do it using a checkbox and a select, so three values but in two "carriers".

Answer (score 1):

to access the data stored in the Objects you are referring to, you can either access it like this:

```
grade.id
```

or like this

```
grade['id']
```

If you are uncertain if an object contains any given property, you can check like this:

```
grade.hasOwnProperty('id')
```

If you just want to log to console the contents of the object, you can do it like this:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( grade ) );
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: That sadly doesn't work. grade does get a property id, it gets a property named the same as the id of the course I'm trying to change grade of. So can't access it using id since it changes depending on what course I want to change the grade of. Only console log it because I want to see the content atm so I can figure out how to continue.  @Stian

Comment: Then I'm not sure if I understand what your problem actually is? Appeared as you just wanted to use some information stored in the Object?

Comment: I do want to use the information in the object, but if you look at the console log in the beginning, you se that the information is stored in a way that I can't use i.e. grade.id to get it since the property is grade.574d8ce6bfb4ea470a2e10c7 where the number corresponds to the Id of the course I want to change in the database. So I want to extract both 574d8ce6bfb4ea470a2e10c7 and 3 from the grade object. @Stian

Comment: Ahh, now I see. Do you have some more code to look at? For example where you send the data from the html to the nodejs server? and how you receive it on the server?

Comment: Added some more code an explanations, does this make it more clear? @Stian

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing it in so complicated way - `ctrl.save(ctrl.courses)` has all information that need to be saved.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('grades', function() {
    var grades = {}
    grades.courses = [{
      code: 'abc',
      grade: 1
    }, {
      code: 'bca',
      grade: 5
    }, {
      code: 'cab',
      grade: 3
    }]
    grades.available = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return grades
  })
  .controller('firstCtrl', function(grades) {
    this.availableGrades = grades.available
    this.courses = angular.copy(grades.courses)
    this.save = function(courses) {
      grades.courses = angular.copy(courses)

      // as we have all needed data in controller
      // we can also do it like that
      //
      // grades.courses = angular.copy(this.courses)
    }
  })
  .controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, grades) {
    this.availableGrades = grades.available
    this.courses = grades.courses

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return grades.courses
    }, function(courses) {
      this.courses = courses
    }.bind(this))
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='firstCtrl as ctrl'>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='course in ctrl.courses'>
        {{ course.code }} -
        <select ng-model='course.grade' ng-options='grade for grade in ctrl.availableGrades'></select>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click=ctrl.save(ctrl.courses)>Save</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='secondCtrl as ctrl'>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='course in ctrl.courses'>
        {{ course.code }} -
        <select ng-model='course.grade' ng-options='grade for grade in ctrl.availableGrades'></select>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't implement it like that since the database is a bit more complicated. Maybe I didn't explain it properly in the question. The database represent a course planning system for i.e. a university. So there are users, each user have different years in which you place courses. So the courses is all courses offered on the university and can therefore not have a grade property since the grade is personal for every student.